Function or Sub not definded. FindWindow to bringforth an Excel Window
I have used the following code in a previous version of excel without any issues:
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Currently trying to use the same code to bringforth an Excel Window that has been created during execution.
SetForegroundWindow FindWindow("XLMAIN", exportWB.Name & " - Excel")

This gives me an error saying "Function or Sub not defined", and highlights FindWindw in the above line.
I have tried looking for a solution to this everywhere. I suspect it has something to do with my version of Excel. I am working with Microsoft Office 365 and my system is 64bit. I have been looking for a solution to this everywhere but have not been able to find any concrete answer. Please help

I've tested the code w/o issue on M365+Win11.

You have probably placed the call of SetForegroundWindow  in a different module than the definition of it. And as you have used the Private keyword you will get the error message Sub or function not defined.

taller and Storax. Thank you for your support. The code works now. As Storax said, it is a scope issue. Apologies for asking such a silly question and thanks you again.
